# Is possible modify the App Store purchased listing (delete or hide some/unhide other hidden apps)?

Tags: mac-appstore

I have an application listed in my bought applications. I prefer to not see or hide some apps I have purchased in the list of purchased apps. Is there a way to do this? Can I reverse this and unhide these hidden apps at a later date?

For example:
[image: free uninstalled application]

Comment: This question is a candidate for the canonical answer to hiding / deleting iOS App Store purchases. The other one is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/how-to-remove-apps-from-the-purchased-list-in-the-mac-osx-app-store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on any version of the Mac App Store and iTunes App store for iTunes versions older than 10.5

It appears you can now hide iOS App Store purchases in the recently released version of iTunes.

[image]
And you can see them once they're hidden as well as un-hide them if you wish.

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated and now incorrect. Please see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/how-to-remove-apps-from-the-purchased-list-in-the-mac-osx-app-store/27487#27487

Comment: Indeed - thanks for the correction! You can edit any answer here - so feel free to address it yourself - especially when things are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple has not provided a way to do this on either the Mac or iOS app stores.

Please file a bug report with Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com/. You can copy and paste the bug report I filed regarding this issue from here: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1338401 and be sure to note that it is a duplicate of [rdar://10115627](http://rdar://10115627).

Apple encourages duplicate bug reports as it helps them prioritize issues. This is one I'd love to see resolved.

Here's a copy of the bug report I filed:

> Summary:
>
> Since the addition of the "purchased" tab in both the iOS and Mac App
>   Stores it is trivial for anyone using your device to view a full
>   history of every app ever purchased on your account. This does not
>   seem in keeping with Apple's otherwise impeccable record with regard
>   to protecting their customer's privacy.
>
> Steps to Reproduce:
>
> 1. Open App Store
> 2. Click Purchased along the top of the window
> 3. Scroll
> 4. You will not find a delete feature to remove items from this list
>
> Expected Results:
>
> A delete button that will allow for the permanent removal of an
>   application from purchase history.
>
> Actual Results:
>
> No way to delete items from the list.
>
> Notes:
>
> It would be fine if deleting an application produced a warning
>   indicating that if the purchase record is removed the user will have
>   to pay the next time they want to acquire  this application.