# How do I unhide purchases from the App Store?

Tags: itunes, applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is possible modify the App Store purchased listing (delete or hide some/unhide other hidden apps)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24911/is-possible-modify-the-app-store-purchased-listing-delete-or-hide-some-unhide-o)

I hid an app listed in my purchased list by accident, how would I go about getting in back?

Comment: Some more info might be useful: e.g. what did you delete it on? (iOS device, iTunes)

Comment: See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24911/is-possible-modify-the-app-store-purchased-listing-delete-or-hide-some-unhide-h/24916#24916) for pictures.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your account in iTunes on your computer by selecting your Apple ID on the top right in the iTunes Store.
2. Select *view hidden purchases*.
3. Find the app and unhide.

[image]