# Does an app downloaded on one device automatically show up another device using the same Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

If two people are sharing an Apple ID and one decides to download an app on their device will it show up downloaded on the other persons device? This may sound like a crazy question but I am pretty certain it can't happen but I was wanting to double check.

Answer (score 11):

If two devices have the same AppleID (typically what would happen if you have an iPhone and an iPad), then if an app is download on one device, it will change the icon in the App Store to show a cloud with an arrow rather then the "Get" or price button.

Additionally, depending on the iTunes & App Store settings in the Settings app, the apps may automatically download to the other device.

[image: iTunes & App Store settings on iPhone]

Answer (score 5):

It will if the iTunes settings on their device are configured to download purchases automatically. Below I have iTunes configured to update apps automatically, but could select apps and if my wife, who uses my Apple ID, bought a new app it would then show up on mine. She has this turned on for hers, so she automatically installs all apps I buy, but I have mine turned off so I don't get the latest coupon app she is trying unless I install it myself.

[image]

This setting can be changed without the Apple ID password, so you cannot be sure they won't get the app you install unless you check their device. You cannot change this setting remotely.

You can [prevent an app from showing up in the purchased list of the app store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24911/is-possible-modify-the-app-store-purchased-listing-delete-or-hide-some-unhide-o), using iTunes on a computer. You cannot change whether it shows up as purchased if you go directly to the app.

So if it's an issue for you, here are your options:

- Make sure they have the iTunes feature to auto download new purchases set to off (won't change the purchased list or app store indication of purchase)
- Use iTunes to remove the app from the purchased list (won't stop auto downloads, nor ownership indication on the app page itself)
- Use a different Apple ID (resolves all the above issues)

Answer (score 2):

You can set this up easily.

Turn on Automatic App downloads in the settings app - be sure to observe if you allow or deny cellular data for downloading. That can prevent apps that are larger than a certain size from downloading over cellular or prohibit all cellular automatic downloads.

Comment: I think OP wanted the opposite behaviour.