# How can I relist an App in App Store Purchased list that was inadvertently deleted?

Tags: mac-appstore

I inadvertently deleted the wrong App from the list of purchased Apps in the Mac App store. I would like to get it back. How can this be done?

I was able to to "Re-Purchase" for free, by searching for the App and clicking buy, but that did not re-add the App to my Purchased list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for both iTunes Apps and the App Store on the Mac.

1. Log into your account via the App Store account link.
2. Look for iTunes in the Cloud
3. Click the View Hidden Purchases link.
4. Select Unhide next to the App you want back in the list.

Items aren't deleted from the list, just merely hidden.

[image: Hidden Purchase in iTunes]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you "Accept" the item which you hid, it is very unclear how to restore the item to the app list.  Here is how to do it from Lion (OSX 10.7.4).

1. Under the Store Menu, select view my account.
2. After entering in your password, you will see a section that shows iTunes in the Cloud
3. Click on the View Hidden Purchases
4. Click Unhide on the Apps you wish to view